# How to avoid getter and setter springboot entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, getter-setter

Is there a way to avoid `getter` and `setter` in the spring-boot entity, sometimes I have a lot of columns in the database?

Comment: You can use lombok. It is a java library. Refer https://projectlombok.org/features/Data

Comment: @NitinBisht   lombok  solved my problem thank you .

Comment: Yes thank you , and if the question was correct upvote question also .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Lombok`. It is a small java library that can be used to reduce the amount of boilerplate java code. `Lombok` does this via annotations that can be added to the java classes.

For `getters/setters` Lombok provides `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations. You can add it to class data fields. it will generate `getter` and `setters` in the background.

**Note:** For detailed information refer https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter